# How to define constant in jboss drools?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, drools, drools-flow

All

I want to know that how to define contant variable in jboss drools rule.

So, Admin has to change only one place to modify the configurable value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You´re able to define global variables within a rule. This variable can be filled via Java like this:

```
public void init() {
        StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = knowledgeBase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();

        String string = "foo";
        // setGlobal 'string' as 'var' in rule
        ksession.setGlobal("var", string);
}
```

In the rule, this global can be accessed via the 'global' keyword:

```
global String var;

rule "Test"
    when
        # actual condition 
    then
        # RHS
end
```

Comment: hey, fnst your are right i can do that way but its not maching with my requirement. i want to initialize constant in rule itself, is that possible ? i searched it on web & forum but could not get any help...

Comment: Yes, I knew that my answer does not quite apply to your request. But I thought it might help anyway. About a definable constant, unfortunately I do not know anything.