# Drools - Best practices for comparing fields not involving primary datatypes

Tags: java, drools, mvel

Is there a better way to define the follow rule?

Following rule checks to see if a person is Overweight (by calling the greaterThan method defined in the Weight class).

**Rule:**

```
rule "OverWeightTest"
 dialect "mvel"
 when
    $person : Person(weight.greaterThan(new Weight(200, Weight.Unit.LBS)) )
 then
    System.out.println($person + " is overweight!");
end
```

**Java Classes:**

```
public class Person
{
    private final String name;
    private final Weight weight;
}

public class Weight
{
    private final int value;
    private final Unit unit;

    public boolean greaterThan(final Weight otherWeight) {
       ...
    }
}
```

- **I'd rather not use Globals** for the constant "200 LBS". Mainly because I want the rule author to mention the weight limit and I don't want to burden the application with it.
- **"200 LBS" **instantiated in-line**. I'd like to separate it out to a different line, so that the rule is more readable. How do I do that?
- **What's the recommended way to compare fields that don't involve primary datatypes** (int, boolean, float, double, etc). In this particular example, it's Weight.

Thanks!!

Comment: to keep things consistent - why not implement `Comparable`? Also see this answer for constants in drools: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381650/how-to-define-constant-in-jboss-drools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if @Laune's answer is the most clean and follows all the best practices, I'll leave this alternative way you have to instantiate objects in the LHS of your rules (maybe because some of the necessary parameters in the constructor comes from a variable bound to a fact).

```
rule "OverWeightTest"
dialect "mvel"
when
    $w: Weight() from new Weight(200, Weight.Unit.LBS)
    $person : Person( weight.greaterThan($w) )
then
    System.out.println($person + " is overweight!");
end
```

Again, I do agree that the rule above will be considered an unholy monstrosity by production rule systems purists!

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for the answer Esteban! You clearly explained how to instantiate a new object in the when section.  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot instantiate objects for static-like variables in DRL code. Technically, you could initialize a global in a rule (with maximum salience) but this would be too late for the inference engine, which would aready be running at that moment, and updates of globals aren't taken into account.

So the best option would be to use a static factory method in the Weight class. *It is better not to call constructors in LHS code.*

```
class Weight {
    public static lbs(int amt ){
        return new Weight(amt, Weight.Unit.LBS);
    }
}
```

and in the rule you use

```
Person( weight.greaterThan(Weight.lbs(200)) )
```

This might advantageously be combined with a static cache for the generated objects.

Implementing Comparable doesn't make this any more readable (although it might be useful for your Java code).

Comment: *It is better not to call constructors in LHS code* - A bit offtopic, but why? I have been doing that sometimes. Too many temporary objects created?

Comment: @GergelyBacso The problem is that you don't have control over the lifetime of the resulting objects. Moreover, it isn't, in general, straightforward to calculate the frequency these instantiations are being executed. - More generally, everything that smells of "side effect" has to be regarded with a wary eye. (Right: even my proposal to call a factory method has a side effect, but a it's a limited one, especially with a cache. Actually, what OP rules out. i.e., the creation in JAva code, would be preferable, but I understand user55's motivation)

Comment: Uhhh. I am sorry, but this was the least specific answer I received in a long time. :) No offense, I see that you answer most of the Drools related questions, it is just that these two sentences were really obscure.

Comment: Not to hijack this thread, I am going to raise a separate question specifically about this problem.